# ASP Classic secure and performance practice for storing global information

Tags: asp-classic, global-variables

I've been using a hard-coded include in what was supposed to be a temporary ASP Classic site to store constants for system parms. These are also stored in a config table in a SQL Server database.

I'll be maintaining this system for another 6 months, so I wondered if I should switch back to using Global.ASA (the site isn't on a farm and won't ever be), or start drawing the settings from the database each time they're needed.

I'd be storing small pieces of data like:
Semester
Start Date
End Date
Key1
Key2
Key3
Key4

I could set these in Session for each user on login, could set them as Application("") vars in Global.Asa, or just pull them from the database each time they're required.

I think I overengineered things when I started worrying about performance and storing globals.

What's a decent way to do this for an app that's got to exist for a while?

Comment: If it is truly only six more months (sounds like it may be more), go with what is working or currently set up.  If it isn't difficult to maintain then why change it?  If it is difficult to maintain, then weigh your time between maintenance with current configuration against the time to consolidate the global parameters.  As far as database or global.asa, for this case I don't think it really matters.  If anything, why have the extra database calls?  I guess another question would be, how many values are we talking about, and how large are they?

Comment: You may be right. There are about 10 values, max, that sit out there.They are mostly short strings and ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make a change then I would recommend storing them as key value pairs in the database (key column and value column), load them into Application variables (dynamically) in the ASA and expose an administration CRUD interface to manage them and reload them. That's the most future proof, and performance wise way to implement this. I have had great success with this pattern on many classic ASP sites.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 10 relatively short variables, I recommend to leave them as is unless updating the design will save you time in the future when you need to update the values.

Given the application use and future you have laid out, I would suggest to just use global.asa for the values.